# Angular charts is not displayed

Tags: angularjs, angular-chart, chart.js

I have created a basic chart using angular chart and chart.js . But I couldn't see any chart representation when I open the html file. When I inspect the browser Im able to see the canvas layout but no chart displayed. What is the mistake Im doing, how to rectify it.

HTML:

```
<head>
   <title>CHART</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src=Chart.js></script>
   <script src="angular-chart.js"></script>    
   <script src="chartExmp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="PolarAreaCtrl">
   <canvas  chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options">
   </canvas> 
</body>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("PolarAreaCtrl", function     ($scope) {
   $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales",  "Tele Sales", "Corporate Sales"];
   $scope.data = [300, 500, 100, 40, 120];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the chart type in the html,

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data" chart-series="series" chart-labels="labels"></canvas>
```

[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/LOpNf9uz773Bk4QPI7hX?p=preview)